# Cannot payout to Stripe Connected Account in another region

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am working on platform on which artists live stream their performances, charge a viewer an entry fee and then they get payout of their earnings (minus the platform fee). We decided to go with Stripe because it supports **40+ countries**.

For charging the customers we have had no problems, but got stuck with the payouts.

Knowing this is the only way to payout the artists we used the payout API call to pay the artists their earnings and got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "transfers_not_allowed",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/transfers-not-allowed",
    "message": "Funds can't be sent to accounts located in DE because it's restricted outside of your platform's region; please contact us via https://support.stripe.com/contact for details.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Which brings a question about if it is possible to send money to artists bank accounts that are in a country that is different from the platforms one. Again the flow should be the artists can be from any of these 40 countries and we should pay them after the stream.

Has anyone had a similar issue, and if so could you please share your experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reach out to [Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) and ask this question.

Comment: Well yes maybe that will the best solution, and I did ask them. But I was wondering is someone else has had similar issue. When I receive an answer I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just had a meeting with the Stripe team and they explained to me that payouts for cross border accounts is not ready yet. You can send payouts to bank account in the same region of the platform, for example if you operate in Germany you can payout to German accounts, but if you want to pay to a US account then that is not possible.